# Div container that has the height of the video

Tags: html, css

I have this sample:

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pWyaLX)

```css
.container-video{
  background:red;
  max-width:500px;
}
video{
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
    <div class="container-video">
      <video autoplay muted loop playsinline poster="https://media.giphy.com/media/5CIRqPOk0141W/giphy.gif">
      <source src="https://multicdn.synq.fm/projects/bb/56/bb56f28429b942c08dc5128e4b7ba48c/derivatives/videos/71/43/71439ccd73c74ecc8bbab7abd3bb98bc/mp4_1080/71439ccd73c74ecc8bbab7abd3bb98bc_mp4_1080.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
      <source src="https://multicdn.synq.fm/projects/bb/56/bb56f28429b942c08dc5128e4b7ba48c/derivatives/videos/71/43/71439ccd73c74ecc8bbab7abd3bb98bc/webm_720/71439ccd73c74ecc8bbab7abd3bb98bc_webm_720.webm" type="video/webm" />
      </video>
    </div>
```

The problem is at the height of the `"container-video"`.
Look at the picture below to understand exactly what the problem is

[image]

Can you help me solve this problem please? thank you

Comment: have you tried height: 100%; in css video ?

Comment: yes but it does not work. I put "height: 100%;" video tag

Comment: add `font-size: 0;` to your container

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please update your css to:

```
.container-video{
  background:red;
  max-width:500px;
}
video{
  width:100%;
  display: block;
}
```

It looks like video default to display: inline.  By changing it to block will force it respect the height.

Answer (score 7):

please add the below code for it to work as you want.

```
video{
  width:100%;
  display: block
}
```

add in display block for the element to behave as a block which will fix your issues. please tick answer if this works for you too.

here you will find the demo link with the fix
[fix demo link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Yrqede)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `line-height:1px;` to `.container-video` like this:

```css
.container-video{
  background:red;
  max-width:500px;
  line-height: 1px;
}
video{
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-video">
  <video autoplay muted loop playsinline poster="https://media.giphy.com/media/5CIRqPOk0141W/giphy.gif">
  <source src="https://multicdn.synq.fm/projects/bb/56/bb56f28429b942c08dc5128e4b7ba48c/derivatives/videos/71/43/71439ccd73c74ecc8bbab7abd3bb98bc/mp4_1080/71439ccd73c74ecc8bbab7abd3bb98bc_mp4_1080.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  <source src="https://multicdn.synq.fm/projects/bb/56/bb56f28429b942c08dc5128e4b7ba48c/derivatives/videos/71/43/71439ccd73c74ecc8bbab7abd3bb98bc/webm_720/71439ccd73c74ecc8bbab7abd3bb98bc_webm_720.webm" type="video/webm" />
  </video>
</div>
```